# Using std::cin from native module

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I have a native module and try to read from `std::cin` but never seem to get any data. Now my question is whether this is possible at all or whether python is silently consuming input into an own buffer.

Comment: Out of desperation I tried `sys.stdin.detach()` but this does not change anything.

Comment: It actually seems like it is possible and works fine. If I build a pipe with `echo` it works fine.